What is the right way of doing custom Authentication in spring WebFlux. In my configuration i have redirect after Authentication problem
I try to implement custom Authentication digital signature based in Spring Cloud Gateway. At this moment i just return true for signature validation.
public class AdsAuthenticationFilter implements WebFilter {
    
    private final ServerRedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultServerRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        if ("/ads-login".equals(exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath())) {
            return authenticate(exchange)
                    .flatMap(authentication -> {
                        SecurityContextImpl securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
                        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);
                        // Set the security context before redirecting
                        return Mono.deferContextual(ctx -> redirectStrategy
                                .sendRedirect(exchange, URI.create("http://127.0.0.1:3000/procur-next"))
                                .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder
                                        .withSecurityContext(Mono.just(securityContext))));
                    })
                    .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange));  // Continue chain if authentication fails
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);  // Proceed normally for other requests
    }

    private Mono<Authentication> authenticate(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        // TODo verifySignature
        String username = "user"; 
        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER"));
        return Mono.just(auth);
    }

}

and my SecurityWebFilterChain btw i have already oauth2 client configured
 public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        final var frontUri = "{baseUrl}" + frontContext;

        return http
                .oauth2Login(login -> login.authenticationSuccessHandler(new SpaAuthenticationSuccessHandler(frontUri)))
                .addFilterBefore(new AdsAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .exceptionHandling(conf -> conf.authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) ->
                        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
                ).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) ->
                        Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
                ))
                .csrf(conf -> conf.disable())
                .formLogin(conf -> conf.disable())
                .httpBasic(conf -> conf.disable())
                .logout(logout -> logout.logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(new SpaLogoutSucessHandler(clientRegistrationRepository, gatewayContext, frontContext)))
                .authorizeExchange(cust -> cust.pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated()
                ).build();
    }


when I test this http://127.0.0.1:8080/ads-login in logs i see
20240513 16:08:11 DEBUG c.d.p.config.AdsAuthenticationFilter:29 - ADS authenticated with principal: user
20240513 16:08:11 DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.DefaultServerRedirectStrategy:54 - Redirecting to 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/procur-next'
...
20240513 16:08:11 DEBUG o.s.b.a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler:127 - [31a178bd-5] Resolved [ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND] for HTTP GET /ads-login
20240513 16:08:11 TRACE o.s.core.codec.CharSequenceEncoder:137 - [31a178bd-5] Writing "<html><body><h1>Whitelabel Error Page</h1><p>This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.</p><div id='created'>Mon May 13 16:08:11 EEST 2024</div><div>[31a178bd-5] There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).</div></body></html>"

It seems like request is not considered processed and Spring try to match request and finally give 404 error. I can avoid this only by creating controller
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RestController
public class ADSController {

    @GetMapping("/ads-login")
    public Mono<Void> adsLogin(ServerWebExchange exchange){
        String redirectUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/procur-next";
        log.debug("redirecting to {}",redirectUrl);
        exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create(redirectUrl));
        // End response processing
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
    }
}

In this case my request is redirected but without session cookie. My question is why Spring continue to find matching and not doing redirect in filter (btw i tried in filter ServerRedirectStrategy or
exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
        exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create(redirectUrl));
        // End response processing
        return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();

but result is the same). And the second question why controller don't see that request is authorized I can see this by commenting out
.authorizeExchange(cust ->
\\ cust.pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
                        .anyExchange().authenticated() 

in this case i get 401 error.
